# How to make a Mysql request to get GLPI data?

Tags: mysql

I have an ip of host where glpi database is installed. I have to make a mysql request to get data from glpi database.

I have also a login and a password.

The basic command like this

```
mysql -h 192.168.1.145 -p
```

gave me an error

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.1.145' (110 
"Connection timed out")
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use this command:

```
mysql -h xxx.xxx.x.xx -u username -p
```

where xxx.xxx.x.xx = your ip address;

Then

```
show databases;
use glpi;
show tables;
```

You will have an access of all tables of glpi BD.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you had forgotten the username, but in your scenario, if you are accessing from another server you might have:

1. Firewall access blocked
2. Mysql access limited to localhost
3. User access limited to localhost